# Allure + Junit: Не формируется Allure-отчет

Tags: java, test-automation, allure

Не могу сформировать Allure отчет в своем автотесте.

Запускаю выполнение автотеста с помощью junit: при выполнении не создается папка allure-results и получаю следующие ошибки:

```
10:18:53.917 [main] ERROR io.qameta.allure.AllureLifecycle - Could not start step: no test case running
10:18:54.316 [main] ERROR io.qameta.allure.AllureLifecycle - Could not update step: no step running
10:18:54.316 [main] ERROR io.qameta.allure.AllureLifecycle - Could not stop step: no step running
10:18:54.317 [main] ERROR io.qameta.allure.AllureLifecycle - Could not start step: no test case running
10:18:54.387 [main] ERROR io.qameta.allure.AllureLifecycle - Could not update step: no step running
10:18:54.387 [main] ERROR io.qameta.allure.AllureLifecycle - Could not stop step: no step running
```

При запуске с помощью maven, получаю следующий ворнинг:

```
[ERROR] Directory C:\git\etc_test\target\allure-results not found.
[WARNING] Allure report was skipped because there is no results directories found.
```

Если я создаю папку allure-results вручную, то при исполнении mvn удалит ее и вернет тот же самый ворнинг.

Мой pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>ru.mos</groupId>
    <artifactId>etc_test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0-RC1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0-RC1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-junit5</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-surefire-plugin -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.10/aspectjweaver-1.8.10.jar"
                    </argLine>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>listener</name>
                            <value>io.qameta.allure.junit5.AllureJunit5</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <property>
                            <name>allure.results.directory</name>
                            <value>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</value>
                        </property>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8.10</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Структура теста:
TestCase5986:

```
package ru.mos;

import io.qameta.allure.*;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TestCase5986 {
    public static LoginPage loginPage;
    public static MainPage mainPage;
    public static WblPage wblPage;
    public static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", ConfProperties.getProperty("chromedriver"));
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
        mainPage = new MainPage(driver);
        wblPage = new WblPage(driver);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get(ConfProperties.getProperty("loginpage"));
    }

    @Epic("Тестирование стенда ETC)
    @Feature(value = "CASE-5986")
    @Severity(SeverityLevel.CRITICAL)
    @Description("Позитивный тест формы логирования в системе")
    @Story (value = "Авторизация с корректным логином")

    @Test
    public void LoginTest() {
        loginPage.inputLogin(ConfProperties.getProperty("login"), ConfProperties.getProperty("password"));
        loginPage.clickSubmitBtn();
        /*mainPage.waybillListClick();
        wblPage.createBtnClick();
        wblPage.carSelect();
        wblPage.createMission();
        wblPage.techOpIdSelect();
        wblPage.facilityIdSelect();
        wblPage.routeIdSelect();
        wblPage.missionSubmitClick();
        wblPage.refillAddRow1();
        wblPage.oneFuelTankContSelect();
        wblPage.depDateFieldInput();
        wblPage.arrivalDateFieldInput();
        wblPage.newDepDate();
        assert wblPage.checkErrorMsg();*/
    }

        @AfterClass
        public static void driverClose () {
        driver.close();

    }

}
```

loginPage:

```
package ru.mos;

import io.qameta.allure.Step;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;

public class LoginPage {
    public WebDriver driver;

    public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    @FindBy(id = "login")
    public WebElement loginFld;
    @FindBy(id = "password")
    public WebElement passwordFld;
    @FindBy(id = "submit")
    public WebElement submitBtn;

    @Step("Ввод логина {login} и пароля {password}")
    public void inputLogin(String login, String password) {
        loginFld.sendKeys(login);
        passwordFld.sendKeys(password);

    }
    
    @Step ("Подтверждение авторизации")
    public void clickSubmitBtn() {
        submitBtn.click();
    }

}
```

У меня два предположения:

1. чего-то не хватает в pom.xml;
2. некорректное использование аннотаций.

UPD:
При выполнении команды allure:serve формируется пустой отчет:
[image: Пустой allure-отчет]

UPD2: Лог Maven при выполнении кейса:

```
C:\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\java.exe -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\git\TestNGAllure_test "-Dmaven.home=C:\Users\TinkovAY\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Users\TinkovAY\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-Dmaven.ext.class.path=C:\Users\TinkovAY\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven-event-listener.jar" "-javaagent:C:\Users\TinkovAY\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=52132:C:\Users\TinkovAY\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Users\TinkovAY\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.6.0.jar;C:\Users\TinkovAY\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds.license" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2020.2.1 clean test -Dsuite=src/test/resources/testng.xml.xml -Dversion=83.0 allure:serve
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------< ru.dit:TestNGAllure_test >----------------------
[INFO] Building TestNGAllure_test 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ TestNGAllure_test ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\git\TestNGAllure_test\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ TestNGAllure_test ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) @ TestNGAllure_test ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ TestNGAllure_test ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ TestNGAllure_test ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 5 source files to C:\git\TestNGAllure_test\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.20:test (default-test) @ TestNGAllure_test ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running TestSuite
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 7.034 s - in TestSuite
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- allure-maven:2.10.0:serve (default-cli) @ TestNGAllure_test ---
[INFO] Allure installation directory C:\git\TestNGAllure_test/.allure
[INFO] Try to finding out allure 2.8.1
[INFO] Generate Allure report (serve) with version 2.8.1
[INFO] Generate Allure report to C:\git\TestNGAllure_test\target\site/allure-maven-plugin
[INFO] Found results directory C:\git\TestNGAllure_test\target\allure-results
[INFO] Can't find information about categories.
[INFO] Generate report to C:\git\TestNGAllure_test\target\site\allure-maven-plugin
Generating report to temp directory...
Report successfully generated to C:\Users\TinkovAY\AppData\Local\Temp\6365362014998145974\allure-report
Starting web server...
2020-08-26 15:35:45.363:INFO::main: Logging initialized @2065ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
Server started at <http://10.159.209.98:52175/>. Press <Ctrl+C> to exit
```

Структура проекта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А тесты-то вообще запускаются? У Вас, в коде теста (как приведено тут) - ошибка - `@Epic("Тестирование стенда ETC)` - нет закрывающих кавычек. Также, у Вас в pom.xml сразу и JUnit 4 и JUnit 5 объявлены

Comment: Тест запускается, в тесте кавычки присутствуют, это ошибка появилась при редактировании вопроса, я удалял стенд

Comment: А можете привести вывод Maven?

Comment: Добавил лог в конец вопроса

Comment: Я отчаялся найти решение с использованием Junit, поэтому подключил в автотест TestNG, с новой конфигурацией создается папка allure-results, но все еще генерится пустой отчет в браузере

Comment: Так у Вас мавен показывает что ни один тест не был запущен - поэтому и отчет пустой. Проверьте что Ваши тесты лежат в src/test/java и запускаются при выполнении mvn test

Comment: Вывод запуска `maven`-а не соотвествует указанному `pom.xml` (`-Dsuite=src/test/resources/testng.xml.xml`). Можете привести пример запуска `maven` с использованием `JUnit 5`?

Comment: @sergi структура моего проекта на скриншоте в конце вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, я смог решить проблему, опишу шаги:

1. Поскольку у меня было мало примеров написания автотестов на junit, а те, что были - не работали, я перешел на TestNG - это будем считать первым шагом.
2. Далее я отредактировал свой pom.xml:

   4.0.0

   ```
    <groupId>ru.dit</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestNGAllure_test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.webdriver/webdriver-selenium -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.webdriver</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdriver-selenium</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.7376</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.qameta.allure/allure-testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
            <artifactId>allure-testng</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0-alpha2</version>
            <!--scope>test</scope-->
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.codeborne/selenide -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenide</artifactId>
            <version>5.14.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.20</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <!--suppress MavenModelInspection -->
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <argLine>
                        -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                    </argLine>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <allure.results.directory>${project.build.directory}/allure-results</allure.results.directory>
                        <!--Используется для конфигурации selenida-->
                        <selenide.reports>${basedir}/target/allure-results/screenshot</selenide.reports>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                        <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.qameta.allure</groupId>
                <artifactId>allure-maven</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <reportVersion>2.8.1</reportVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
   ```
3. Благодаря комментарию @Alexandr, я заметил ошибку в maven command line, убрал лишнее .xml, теперь maven стал видеть мой suite-файл;
4. Затем я заметил в выводе maven такую строку:

   [INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

Тут до меня дошло, что не смотря, что тест выполняется, информация о нем никак не передается allure (или maven, или maven, а затем allure) и у меня строится пустой отчет. Тогда я обратил внимание на свой testng.xml. Так он выглядел в старой версии:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Тестирование базовых функций ЕТС">
    <test name="Authorization" >
        <packages>
            <package name="java/ru.mos" />
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Я ожидал, что maven будет забирать классы из пакета, в которых присутствуют аннотации @test и @class, поскольку это не работало, я указал классы и методы более конкретно, тогда мой testng.xml стал выглядеть следующим образом:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Тестирование базовых функций ЕТС">
<test name="Authorization">
    <classes>
        <class name="ru.mos.TestCase5986">
            <methods>
                <include name="loginTest"/>
            </methods>
        </class>
    </classes>
</test>
</suite>
```

Теперь тест-кейс выполняется и allure отчет строится корректно.
Всем спасибо за помощь!